# Uploading file with other form fields in Angular 2 and Spring MVC

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, file-upload, angular2-forms

I am trying to **upload file and other form field contents** from my Angular 2 front end to Spring back end. But somehow I am not able to do it. Here is my code:

**app.component.ts**

```
fileChange(e){
    this.fileList = e.target.files;
  }

uploadPdf(){
    if(this.fileList.length>0){
      let file: File = this.fileList[0];
      let formData:FormData = new FormData();

      formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
      formData.append('info',this.model);

      console.log(file.size);

      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      this.http.post(this.url,formData, options)
        /*.map((res: Response) => res.json())*/
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
        .subscribe(
          data =>{
            this.data = data;
            console.log(this.data);
          }
          ,
          error => console.log(error)
        )
    }
  }
```

**app.cmoponent.html**

```
<h1 class="text-center">
  PDF Viewer and Uploader Example
</h1>
<div class="text-center">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name: </label>
      <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email: </label>
      <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="model.email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pdfInput">Select File: </label>
      <input type="file" id="pdfInput" class="form-control" name="pdfInput" (change)="fileChange($event)">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="uploadPdf()">Upload File!</button><span>   </span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="printData()">Print to Console!</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**model.ts**

```
export class Model{

  name: string;
  email: string;

}
```

Now in Backend:

**ExampleModel.java**

```
public class ExampleModel {

private String name;
private String email;
//Getters and Setters
```

**MainController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestParam("uploadFile") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("info") ExampleModel model){}
```

So, how to get that `info` labeled data in the spring controller? Above I have shown my attempt which is wrong so, what is the correct approach to get other form fields data?

How the Controller method with annotations should be defined or is there other way to send data(both file + form fields) from Angular 2?

Comment: what's wrong with this?

Comment: @RomanC I am not able to get the data in my spring controller. I can get the file with RequestParam and other form fields individually with RequestParam, but how to get the whole model and file alone or all of them together?

Comment: It works for me, but I need to remove 'options' from POST request, like this: this.http.post(this.url,formData)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` and set `consumes` attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/file",method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@RequestPart("uploadFile") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("info") ExampleModel model){}
```

You also need to adjust your `FormData` object:

```
formData.append('uploadFile', file, file.name);
formData.append('info', new Blob([JSON.stringify(this.model)],
        {
            type: "application/json"
        }));
```

Comment: Tried and got this error:- HTTP Status 400 - Required request part 'info' is not present

Comment: It worked...Thanks and do you know if I can send all of these(file+data) together? rather than appending individually?

Comment: @Dishank You're welcome. I don't think you can send them together, you must have two separate objects in `FormData`, one for file and the other one for JSON object.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota I tried this approach for my problem which is very much similar to this. But it did not work. I changed `@RequestParam` to `@RequestPart`. But still I get  `Required request part 'file' is not present"` error. Can you kindly have a look into following question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44139831/angular2-formdata-with-post-request-required-request-part-file-is-not-presen.

Comment: It works for me, but I need to remove 'options' from POST request, like this: this.http.post(this.url,formData)

Comment: Any thoughts on how to get this done using dotnet core?

Comment: when i remove option , i have HTTP 415 error Content type 'application/json' not supported]  .i am sending multipart though

Answer (score 1):

i'm tryning to use formData to send both myobject and a file form angular 2 to spring mvc deploed on websphere:

ao.component.ts is:

```
let input=new FormData();
    input.append('appelOffre', new Blob([JSON.stringify(appelOffre)],
        {
            type: "application/json"
        }));
    input.append('compteRendu',file);

    this._aoService.uploadAppelOffre(input)
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log('success'),
      error => console.log(error)
  );
```

service is:

```
uploadAppelOffre(input : FormData):  Observable<number>{

  const headers = new Headers();
  const cpHeaders = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: cpHeaders });
  return this.http.post(this.uploadUrl, input, options)
  .map(this.extractData)
  .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
```

}

ang my spring service is:

```
@RequestMapping(value="uploadfile", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"multipart/form-data"} )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> addFile(@RequestPart("compteRendu") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("appelOffre") AppelOffre ao){

        if(!file.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("accepted: "+file.getOriginalFilename());
            File convFile = new File( file.getOriginalFilename());
            try {
                file.transferTo(convFile);
                ao.setLien_alfresco_cr(convFile.getAbsolutePath());
               // service.addAppelOffre(ao);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);

    }
```

Now using tomcat and mysql it works fine , but once deploed on web sphere i get the problem: [03/01/18 10:21:50:148 GMT] 0000008c srt           W com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse setHeader SRVE8094W: AVERTISSEMENT : Impossible de définir l'en-tête. La réponse a déjà été validée.

and in console: 
POST http://localhost:4200/gtaows/services/uploadfile 415 (Unsupported Media Type)

thx,

Comment: Try after removing the **Content-type** in your service. as per my knowledge while working with file upload you need to keep it empty.

Comment: i got the error when removing content type "Error 400: SRVE0295E:  "Bad Request"

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution :

It is very **important** to leave the **Content-Type** empty. If you set the 'Content-Type' to 'multipart/form-data' the upload will not work !

**upload.component.html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" name="file" />
```

**upload.component.ts**

```
  fileChange(event): void {
        const fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
        if (fileList.length > 0) {
            const file = fileList[0];

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file, file.name);

            const headers = new Headers();
            // It is very important to leave the Content-Type empty
            // do not use headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9....');
            const options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

            this.http.post('https://api.mysite.com/uploadfile', formData, options)
                 .map(res => res.json())
                 .catch(error => Observable.throw(error))
                 .subscribe(
                     data => console.log('success'),
                     error => console.log(error)
                 );
        }
    }
```