# Spring Boot rest controller call

Tags: angular, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to send file and other values to rest controller from angular service. but

```
@PostMapping("/rest")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponse> upload(@RequestBody Entity entity){

}
```

this method causing infinite loop and due to that application is not getting started.
I have tried [Uploading file with other form fields in Angular 2 and Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064548/uploading-file-with-other-form-fields-in-angular-2-and-spring-mvc) but any modification other than only `@RequestParam`  argument  in method definition is cuasing infinite loop while spring-boot application starts.

if i change method signature to  upload(@RequestParam("File") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("additionalInformation") Info info)

application does not starts as it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I am having hard-time understanding your question.

Comment: @PostMapping("/rest")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<FileUploadResponse> upload(@RequestParam("file") Entity entity){

} this method works perfectly to save the file but to get additional parameters I am modifying the method definition which is causing problem and  application is not starting as its getting stuck in infinite loop.

Comment: What part of your program is looping? The only code that you've posted is a method declaration with an empty body.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Spring MVC, I'm working with Jersey and what i did in your case was create a class with pdf bytes attribute and the other attributes, and then just send it.

```
Class PdfRest
{
 byte[] bArray;
 String name;
}
```

Then just do something like

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf");
out.write(bArray);
out.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply I have tried sending through individual object but somehow my application is not getting starting due to this method signature modification. I am not getting what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation what I did is use spring multi-part. Spring offers for multipart (file upload) support in web applications.
Here is my code :

```
@PostMapping("/uploadTest")
public ServiceResponse<String> uploadTestFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable("id") Integer id){
     return new ServiceResponse<>(paymentService.uploadFile(file,id));
}
```

You can use [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-file-upload) article for reference. You can add additional parameters as I have used id.